# How to make the characters in the middle?

Tags: html, css

Previously I use the same code to render my page, but recently when I use `border-radius` to set a circle border, I found the characters are not in the just middle place, I'm confused and I tried all most methods I can think, but I still can't to do it;

I know my code has a bug, I want to know how to correct my code.

This is HTML fragment:

```css
.circle_container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle_container">

  one

</div>
```

The result is:

[image: 1]

You can see that picture the characters is not precisely in center.
What can I do to reach my destination?

Comment: i ran the code and it seems like theres no problem, its center aligned already, its just the text-align you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine, but the base line minds also upper character **(ONE)** and leaves also space for letters such as **ypqgj**, so the middle does not strike in the middle of the word <s>one</s> necessarily.

Here is a few example to let you see how it works.

- 1 `line-height:80px` and capital-letters
- 2 `line-height` decreased a bit to match lower letters
- 3 An inline box resetting `line-height` and `vertical-align` set to middle (that trick already worked in IE5 ... )The tallest element on a line will set the line-height of that line, inline boxes stand on the baseline like text does, vertical-align will align it to the other inline boxes or text aside.

```css
.circle_container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* demo purpose, to see it better */
  background: linear-gradient(to top, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%), linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%);
  transform: scale(3);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.lower {
  line-height: calc(80px * 0.95);
  /* demo purpose, to see it better */
  margin-top: 170px
}

.lower.pseudo {
  line-height: initial;
}

.lower.pseudo:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px blue;/*see me **/
  transform:translateX(42px);/* see it match circle's height */
}

.lower.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
  border-color:tomato;
}

.lower.flex:before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
Which one of these do really set the text right in the middle ? pick one up ;)
<div class="circle_container">

  PpKkOo .-°

</div>
<div class="circle_container lower">

  PpKkOo .-°

</div>
<div class="circle_container lower pseudo">

  PpKkOo .-°

</div>
<div class="circle_container lower pseudo flex">

  PpKkOo .-°

</div>
<div class="circle_container lower pseudo flex">

  flex

</div>
```

Have fun learning and discover CSS behaviors, keep testing and playing around to understands what CSS rules involve.

I would use `flex` or `grid` to make it easier to master, but its nice to know what's happening.

Comment: Yes this is a very important aspect that most the other answers don't touch on, `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

The CSS display value flex helps here. You don't need the text-align or the line-height properties to be set, just set flex and the justify-content and align-items properties.

```css
.circle_container {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle_container">

  one

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because it's a lower case word:

```css
.circle_container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

body
{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle_container">

  one

</div>

<div class="circle_container">

  ONE

</div>
```

Comment: This concept (that the space allotted for a character is not the same size as the space taken up by a character) should be expanded upon, but it's an important aspect other posts here seem to oversight.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flexbox in your CSS. Add the attribute `align-items: center` and it will make your content vertically centered, and the last attribute to add is `justify-content: center`, which makes your content horizontally centered.

All together as following:

```
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content: center;
```

Answer (score 1):

I will go this way, right **in the middle of two y-coordinates (real center)**:

```css
.circle_container {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle_container"  style="display: inline-block">
  one
</div>

<div class="circle_container"  style="display: inline-block">
  ONE
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Flexbox

**The CSS flexbox** is a display type, and it gives you full control over your elements. In your cases we will be using `align-items`(vertical align) and `justify-content`(horizontal align).

```css
.circle_container {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle_container">

  one

</div>
```